Search console notification
Any api to get notifications displayed under bell icon in google search console to my node.js app. Or any other way to get that notifications to my app.
Any api to get notifications displayed under bell icon in google search console to my node.js app. Or any other way to get that notifications to my app. I have searched for api. Not got.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
